# Is there a monster with the upper body of a human from the waist up, and the lower body of a snake?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, content-identification

Nagas and Lamias have various representations in mythology and fiction. One of them is that of a human upper-body (waist up) and the lower body of a snake. What I'm looking for would have a torso, human arms and a human head that could fool someone into thinking they're human until they see their lower body, a large snake body on which it slithers to move about (see visual examples below). 
I think the easiest way to picture what I have in mind is to think "centaur" with snake instead of horse. Snaketaur?

In Pathfinder, the closest to this I could find is the Marilith, if not for the extra arms.

Some examples that don't work and why:

- [Nagas](http://www.pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Water_naga) in Pathfinder are mostly large snakes with a human-like head. They are missing a human torso with human arms to fit my goal.
- [Serpentfolk](http://www.florianstitz.de/uploads/tx_rfgalleria/015serpentfolk-warrior.jpg), Yuan-ti or Nagaji are fully humanoid and walk on legs. They do not slither on their body/tail.

**Is there a monster that fits the description more closely in Pathfinder?**

I'm interested in a ready-made set of stats mostly. It may be a generic monster or specifically from the Golarion setting, I don't mind.

Visual examples of what I'm looking for:

- [Raja Naga from Megami Tensei](http://megamitensei.wikia.com/wiki/Raja_Naga)
- http://yaichino.deviantart.com/art/Naga-138780464
- [Female Naga](http://www.elfwood.com/~audrey86/Female-Naga.2549170.html) (minus wings and tail length quite optional)
- [Naga from Might & Magic](http://www.coins.ro/mightandmagic/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Heroes-Naga-02.jpg) (I could do with a more human face, but otherwise fits)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, the [Lamia Matriarchs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/monstrous-humanoids/lamia/lamia-matriarch) (prominently featured in Rise of the Runelords) have female upper bodies and a snake for a lower body.

Answer (score 12):

You're probably thinking of the [Yuan-ti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuan-ti), but they're not part of the OGC, and so are not part of Pathfinder either.  In their [Malison](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Yuan-ti#Yuan-ti_Breeds) breed variant, they can have a number of features, among which is having a tail instead of legs.

However, Pathfinder has the [Serpentfolk](http://paizo.com/PRD/additionalMonsters/serpentfolk.html).

Quoth TvTropes.org:

> The serpentfolk are similar to D&D's yuan-ti in function (ancient evil snake folk living in ruins) but different in appearance, powers, and culture. In a way, they're more of a return to form—yuan-ti were ersatzes of Robert E. Howard's serpentfolk. Pathfinder's serpentfolk are for all practical purposes identical to the archenemies of King Kull.

There also appears to be a [Nagaji](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-nagaji) race, that seems to be closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Serpentfolk are humanoids with two human legs. The tail in the description is in addition to their legs, àla Catfolk. I'm looking for a creature that slithers on its body-tail. Preferably, it should look perfectly human from the waist up, like a centaur.

Comment: Total side question: how does one access this Additional Monsters list from the root of the PRD?

Comment: Yuan-ti can slither on their tail, if they are [malisons](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Yuan-ti#Yuan-ti_Breeds).
The Additional Monsters list seems to be the Pathfinder [Bestiary 2](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/additionalMonsters/additionalMonsterIndex.html).

Answer (score 8):

While not a set of ready made stats, the Unfettered Eidolon from the Bestiaries 3 can serve well. Use the Serpentine base with the Arms evolution and build from there. Since at least the description from the Summoner class(which is where Eidolon come from) specifically states that they can look like whatever the summoner desires, you can get one that fits.

It's one of, if not the most, customizable monster in Pathfinder.

Comment: Funnily enough, I am planning to use this look for an Eidolon, though I wanted to know if it was already an existing monster. I didn't know of Summoner-less Eidolons, though. Opens up a whole lot of possibilities!

Comment: In addition, from the Ultimate Magic, they have a 'ready-built' evolution list for a Merfolk, that with a couple minor tweaks, could be a humanoid serpent of the type you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Another way that is quite simple is to make a weresnake. You even get to choose what type of snake. Just apply the lycanthrope template with chosen snake from bestiary and boom snekman. You would get the option to be either a normal human (or whatever you use as base), a snake or the hybrid form (amazing snekman).

Lycanthrope template: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/lycanthrope/ 
Snakes: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/snake

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [Merfolk](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-merfolk/). Giving them the "strong tail" alternate trait makes them viable on land as well as in the water.

True; these are fish, not snakes, but they are rather close, and describing them as "half sea-snake" would fix most cosmetic problems

Answer (score 0):

I have a mini from the 2004 (3.5e) era called the ["Ophidian"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophidian_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)). While it has tiny back legs, the Wikipedia article shows some classic stuff where at least some versions (original version in 1983) do not have back legs. Although, they don't look super humanoid, so maybe this isn't what you want.

Quote:

> The ophidian first appeared in the original first edition *Monster
>   Manual II* (1983).

It's in the *Fiend Folio* for 3/3.5e, page 133, and in the picture it has legs. This is definitely the mini I have.

> Malicious but servile, ophidians are a reptilian race most commonly
>   found as slaves of the yuan-ti. They look like large snakes with
>   humanoid arms and hands, and they have tails that are short and
>   stunted in proportion to their bodies. Their scales are typically
>   mottled green and yellow, with brown, black, and red sometimes
>   appearing in certain individuals. Their scales naturally change color
>   to help the creatures blend into wooded or subterranean surroundings.

And I like this:

> **Serpentine Curse (Su):** Any humanoid hit by an ophidian’s bite attack
>   must succeed on a Fortitude save (DC 11) or contract a curse that will
>   turn the victim into an ophidian. Starting 1d4+1 days after infection,
>   the victim slowly becomes more snakelike: Its skin grows scaly, its
>   legs begin to shrink and fuse together, and its tongue becomes forked.
>   After two weeks, the victim is fully transformed into an ophidian,
>   with no memory of its previous existence. To stop the transformation,
>   the victim must receive a *remove disease* or *remove curse* spell before
>   the process is complete, although these spells do not undo any
>   transformation that has already begun. A *heal*, *regeneration*, *limited
>   wish*, *wish*, or *miracle* spell is required to reverse the
>   transformation. Once the transformation is complete, nothing short of
>   a *wish* or *miracle* can return the victim to its previous state.

Comment: They do lack a clearly human upper half (think centaur). The rest would have worked :)  And no I'm not actively looking for an answer to this but someone else might be, or could be in the future, so thanks!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score -1):

Sthein - this is the one you want, offspring of a Royal Naga and an Elf, they leave home once they mature (lion style thrown to the wilds) to learn

Comment: Hi Arthur, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. It looks like this could be the right answer but it would help if you have a source or reference for your answer. Do you know what book they were published in? Or have a link to where they can be found? Adding that information to your answer would make it most useful. Good luck and happy gaming!